# Cant Output the JSON Data Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I successfully outputed the Temperature and Wave, but I cant figure out how to output the Signal inside of gateways array.

```
<?php
$data = '{
    "name": "Aragorn",
    "race": "Human",
     "payload_fields": {
        "temperature": 700
     },
     "metadata": {
        "wave": -600,
        "gateways": [{
            "signal": -80,
            "connection": 1 
        }]
     }
}';

$device = json_decode($data);
//SUCCESS
echo $device->payload_fields->temperature; 
echo "<br>";
//SUCCESS
echo $device->metadata->wave;
echo "<br>";
//FAILED HERE
echo $device->metadata->gateways->signal;
```

Heres the output

```
700
-600

NOTICE Trying to get property of non-object on line number 25
```

line 25 is the last line in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely your `gateways` node contains *array* of object entries, not just one.

So for the first one it would be:

```php
echo $device->metadata->gateways[0]->signal;
```

Comment: Works well, thank you! Gonna accept the answer after 11 mins. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the gateways are in an array, do this.

```
echo $device->metadata->gateways[0]->signal;
```